# Ignore an input field - filter() jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using filter() to check if there are any blank input fields. How can I ignore 1 particular input field which has the same class.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){   
      var findBlank = $(".common").filter(function(){
          return !$.trim($(this).val()).length;
      }).length; 
      if(!findBlank) {
         //go...
      }
});
```

Comment: What makes it specific? I mean how do you target this input? Class, ID, other attribute or what?

Comment: I think you want to use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) but you haven't posted enough details to be sure.

Comment: @A.Wolff I think `.common` is the input selector.

Comment: @Vega Ya but what about specific input to exclude?

Comment: um, this works already right? http://jsbin.com/nuxita/1/edit?console,output

Comment: @A.Wolff Agreed, this part _How can I ignore 1 particular input field which has the same class._ is little confusing.

Comment: @A.Wolff: I want to leave off 1 input text field. This specific input filed is as `<input type="text" class="common" id="grapes">`. And the other input text fields is as `<input type="text" class="common" id="mango">`, `<input type="text" class="common" id="pineapple">`, `<input type="text" class="common" id="apple">`, etc... So 1 class to every input field and now I want to ignore only `<input type="text" class="common" id="stew">` from filtering. Hope that is clear.

Comment: @Vega see above comment.

Comment: So ya, use e.g: `$(.common').not('#stew').filter(...)`

Comment: @A.Wolff Good one, but I still would recommend using 1 function and add the condition in the filter like `return !$.trim($(this).val()).length && this.id != 'stew'`

Comment: @Vega I agree, I find it more readble after all

Comment: @Vega: good point. Thanks 1+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class check to the return condition like below,

```
// ---------------------------------------------v Class check
return !$.trim($(this).val()).length && !$(this).hasClass('yourclass');
```

**Edit:** Updated to use ID selector

```
return !$.trim($(this).val()).length && this.id != 'stew'
```

Comment: So why not `$(".common:not(.yourclass)").filter(...);`?

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, he could use `:not` selector, but then using `:not` adds an extra iteration. Not a big deal though.

Comment: Ya and anyway filtering matched set inside filter() makes it finally more readable, good point ;)

Comment: @Vega: `!$(this).hasClass('yourclass');` checks if any of the selected elements have a specified class name. But in my case the condition should match the ID coz all elements have the same class `class="common"`.

Comment: @Fergoso I had it updated in my comment, now added in the answer. Let me know if it worked for you.